# Python/Tkinter: loading a PhotoImage from within a class

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code defines a custom tkinter button as a class. The class includes a .png image file which sits in the button. If I load the png file within the main application and pass it to this class, it displays correctly. However, as you can see in this code, I would rather have the class load the image itself. However, this does not work. I get the 'no such file or directory' error message. Note that the png image file is in the same folder as the class document, so I can see no reason why it shouldn't work. But it doesn't.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyButton(tk.Button):
  def __init__(self,master,placecol,placerow,btntext):
    super().__init__(master)

    # initialize instance variables
    self.master = master
    self.placecol = placecol
    self.placerow = placerow
    self.btntext = btntext

    # load button image
    btnimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="GreenButton.png")

    # set parameters based on instance variables
    self.configure(text=btntext)
    self.place(x=placecol,y=placerow)
    self.image = btnimage
    self.configure(image=btnimage)
    
    # set additional parameters
    self.configure(borderwidth=0)
    self.configure(fg="white")
    self.configure(bg="#2B2B2B")
    self.configure(activebackground="#2B2B2B")
    self.configure(activeforeground="white")
    self.configure(compound=tk.CENTER)
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: A "no such file or directory" error is unrelated to whether or not you use classes. As long as the image file is in your current working directory, it can be loaded with or without a class.

Comment: Thank you. The class and image file are in a folder together, separate from the main application. Is that the problem then? That the main app, the module and the image need to be in the same folder together?

Comment: If you don't give an absolute path, python looks in the current working directory. That directory could be anywhere - it could be where the main file is, this other file, or literally any other folder.